# ¿Cómo validar una contraseña en PHP?

Tags: php

**Tengo una contraseña** en una variable `$password`. **Quiero verificar que tiene al menos 8 caracteres y que no tenga espacios o caracteres raros** que puedan causar errores (Ej: ¶).

Sé que hay otros temas abiertos, pero todos ellos tienen otras verificaciones que no necesito y no sé cómo quitar (mayúsculas, números, etc).

Mi código es el siguiente, y no funciona, y además no tiene la verificación de espacios y caracteres raros (Ej: ©):

```
<?php

function is_valid_password($password) {
    if (preg_match_all('$S*(?=S{8,})S*$', $password) == true) {
        echo "Correcto";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrecto";
    }
}

$pass = "fffffgfff"; //Da incorrecto, y quiero que sea correcto

is_valid_password($pass);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas al menos dos comprobaciones.

Yo lo primero que hacía para una aplicación determinada era **establecer qué caracteres son admisibles para una contraseña y qué tamaño mínimo y máximo puede tener**. Después primero se comprueba el tamaño y seguidamente, si este es aceptable, que cada uno de los caracteres de la contraseña esté admitido.

#### Validación usando funciones

Ejemplo que ***comprueba que los caracteres son válidos***:

```
<?php  


function validateStrChars(string $pw): bool
{
    $ALLOW_CHARS = 'abcABC@#$.-';

    $len = mb_strlen($pw);
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($pw, $i, $i+1, "UTF-8");
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        if ( ! strpbrk($arr[$i], $ALLOW_CHARS)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


/**
 * Tests
 * 
 */

$pw1 = 'aABa@';
$pw2 = 'aABXX';

var_dump(validateStrChars($pw1));
var_dump(validateStrChars($pw2));
```

Resultado:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Ejemplo que ***comprueba que un string está dentro de unos límites de tamaño***:

```
<?php  

function validateStrLength(string $str, int $min_length, int $max_length): bool
{
    $len = mb_strlen($str);

    return (($len >= $min_length) && ($len <= $max_length));
}


/**
 * Tests
 * 
 */

$pw0 = '1234';
$pw1 = '12345';
$pw2 = '12345678';
$pw3 = '123456789';

var_dump(validateStrLength($pw0, 5, 8));
var_dump(validateStrLength($pw1, 5, 8));
var_dump(validateStrLength($pw2, 5, 8));
var_dump(validateStrLength($pw3, 5, 8));
```

Resultado:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

#### Validación usando clases y métodos

Puedes llevar las validaciones a algo más genérico, ya que al final **se están validando aspectos concretos sobre un string**, y usar una clase para encapsular los métodos, así por ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Strings {

    public static function validateChars(
        string $str,
        string $valid_chars
    ): bool
    {
        $len = mb_strlen($str);

        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
            $char = mb_substr($str, $i, $i+1, "UTF-8");
            if ( ! strpbrk($char, $valid_chars)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static function validateLength(
        string $str,
        int $min_length,
        int $max_length
    ): bool
    {
        $len = mb_strlen($str);

        return (($len >= $min_length) && ($len <= $max_length));
    }

} // class


/**
 * Tests
 *
 */

$ALLOW_CHARS1 = '0123456789';
$ALLOW_CHARS2 = 'abcABC@#$.-';

$pw0 = '1234';
$pw1 = '12345';
$pw2 = '12345678';
$pw3 = '123456789';
$pw4 = 'aABa@###abc';
$pw5 = 'aABa@###xxx';
$pw6 = 'aABa@###xxx1234';

var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw0, 8, 12)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw1, 8, 12)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw2, 8, 12)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw3, 8, 12)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw4, 8, 12)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw5, 8, 12)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw6, 8, 12)); // bool(false)

var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw0, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw1, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw2, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw3, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw4, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw5, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw6, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(false)

var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw0, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw1, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw2, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw3, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw4, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw5, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateChars($pw6, $ALLOW_CHARS1)); // bool(false)

var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw0, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw0, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw1, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw1, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw2, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw2, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw3, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw3, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw4, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw4, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(true)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw5, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw5, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
var_dump(Strings::validateLength($pw6, 8, 12)
    && Strings::validateChars($pw6, $ALLOW_CHARS2)); // bool(false)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué en el primer ejemplo `$pw2 = 'aABXX';` es false, si no tiene ningún carácter fuera de los permitidos? Gracias.

Comment: @ByBrayanYT - Tops y más fíjate que la 'X' no esta entre los caracteres permitidos, sólo puse las letras 'abc' en minúsculas y mayúsculas para simplificar el ejemplo. Saludos.